# Ubuntu 14.04 и Windows 8 Как настроить загрузчик ОС?

Tags: ubuntu, grub, boot

Загрузчик не видит вторую систему Windows 8.

Перед этим был загрузчик на Windows 8, но потом переустановил Ubuntu... И загрузиться теперь могу только с одной ОС.

**Загрузчик: GNU GRUB version 2.02**

Пробовал разные "repair" и т.д. но не помогло. А вот в чем может быть причина, я без малейшего понятия. Может подскажете как добиться нужного результата? Если нужна информация о разделах и т.д. напишите, добавлю... Заранее спасибо!

**sudo fdisk -l**
[image]

**sudo update-grub**

[image]

Comment: вы, случайно, *efi-раздел* в процессе не удаляли?

Comment: `GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER=yes` у вас в каком-нибудь из файлов `/etc/default/grub` или `/etc/default/grub.d/*` случайно не присутствует? если присутствует — закомментируйте и переустановите загрузчик: `$ sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Насчет того, удалял или нет, не помню, было пару недель назад. /etc/default/grub - директории такой нету

Comment: это файл. а `/etc/default/grub.d` — каталог. в любом случае: запуск update-grub входил в число ваших попыток?

Comment: посмотреть разделы можно, например, командой `$ sudo fdisk -l`

Comment: маленького *fat-ового* раздела, на котором хранятся загрузчики *efi*, как вы видите, нет. посмотрите, есть ли упоминания про *efi* в сообщениях *linux-а*: `dmesg | head | grep -i efi`. пожалуйста, дописывайте информацию в вопрос (с помощью кнопки [edit]) в текстовом виде, а не в комментариях картинкой.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin безрезультатно

Comment: в том смысле, что «список пуст»? значит, *efi* не используется. как я понимаю, скорее всего, вы вряд ли меняли настройки компьютера, поэтому *windows* тоже грузится без использования *efi*, и раздел с *efi* загрузчиками не требуется.

Comment: добавьте пожалуйста, в вопрос то, что возвращает команда `sudo os-prober`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin ничего не возвращает

Comment: значит, не находит загрузчика. если у вас есть какой-нибудь загрузочный носитель с *gnu/linux* (чтобы была возможность загрузиться в случае полной неудачи), можете попробовать записать в [`mbr`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) стандартный «виндовский» загрузчик: `sudo dd if=/usr/lib/syslinux/mbr.bin of=/dev/sda` и перезгрузить компьютер. если всё будет удачно, должна загрузиться *ms/windows*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin прошло все не удачно, загрузился с флешки, что-то там выполнил в терминале, теперь при загрузке есть "Windows 8", но некорректно настроено. При загрузке пишет "No such partition"

Comment: *было не удачно* — т.е. после записи стандартного «виндовского» загрузчика при загрузке он не смог загрузить *ms/windows*?

Comment: о! я совсем упустил из виду *bootable*-флаг. он у вас стоит, судя по выдаче *fdisk -l*, только у первого раздела. попробуйте выставить его и у второго и третьего (те, которые обозначены (см. там же) как *hpfs/ntfs/exfat*, а после этого повторите *sudo update-grub* и выложите его вывод.

Comment: объяснять, как ставить и убирать *bootable*-флаги в текстовом интерфейсе, я думаю, будет слишком долго. воспользуйтесь программой *gparted* — графическая «обёртка» вокруг тоже текстовой программы *parted*. там надо будет нажать правой кнопкой мыши на разделе, выбрать *manage flags* и в открывшемся диалоге отметить флаг *boot*.